# Difference between Goto Definition and Goto Implementation in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, go-to-definition

What is the difference between `Go To Definition` and `Go To Implementation` in Visual Studio?

**Version:** Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Comment: I can understand your confusion.  The differences are subtle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's say we have this interface:

```
public interface IEmailSender
{
    Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message);
}
```

And a class that implements this interface:

```
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender
{
    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

If we right click on `IEmailSender` and choose Go To Implementation, Visual Studio navigates us to the class that implements this interface, namely `AuthMessageSender`. 

If we right click on `IEmailSender` while we are in `AuthMessageSender` class and 
choose Go To Definition, Visual Studio navigates us to the definition of the `IEmailSender`.

Comment: So in short: you _define_ an interface and you _implement_ a class for some interface.