# VSCode goto implementation, goto definition, goto type definition, difference

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed VSCode has the following

- goto implemementation
- goto definition
- goto type definition

I'm a bit confused as to how these work, sometimes they even open up a peek definition.  Can someone please provide a practical example on the usages of this.  I found the following [Difference between Goto Definition and Goto Implementation in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433800/difference-between-goto-definition-and-goto-implementation-in-visual-studio) but its lacking goto type definition.

Answer (score 9):

Well, go to type definition does exactly what it says.

[VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) provides us all that info:

> **Go to Type Definition**
>
> Some languages also support jumping to the type definition of a symbol
>   by running the Go to Type Definition command from either the editor
>   context menu or the Command Palette. This will take you to the
>   definition of the type of a symbol. The command
>   editor.action.goToTypeDefinition is not bound to a keyboard shortcut
>   by default but you can add your own custom keybinding.

---

Regarding your questions:

> sometimes they even open up a peek definition

It shows peek definition popup window when it found more than one candidate, and leave to you choose where to jump.

> I'm a bit confused as to how these work

These terms have meaning for some languages, such as C#, and full support of VS Code. In other languages, such as Ruby, despite having Interfaces, VS Code seems have no support for `Go To Implementation` for example. Then you have JavaScript, which does not have Interfaces, in this case `Go To Implementation` routes to `Go To Definition`.

> Can someone please provide a practical example on the usages of this.

You already have `Go To Implementation` and `Go To Definition`, here it goes `Go To Type Definition` (since it's been a while I haven't coded this type of language, I may be wrong in some detail):

```
1: class Animal
2: end
3:
4: Animal dog = new Animal();
```

In line `4`:

- `Go To Type Definition` on symbol "dog" -> l1
- `Go To Definition` on symbol "dog" -> l4
- `Go TO Definition` on symbol "Animal" -> l1

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing language specific modules if the above mentioned commands do nothing. When I began to work with golang, none of these commands worked. I had to install a few modules/commands such as gopls, go-outline, guru, and godef, which were prompted for the installation by VS Code. After that support for browsing experience became similar to what we have in Visual Studio for C#.